# Difference betweet style['property'] and style.property for manipulate style

Tags: javascript

What is difference betweet betweet `element.style['property']='value'` and `element.style.property='value'` for manipulate style in javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference it's just different syntax

In JavaScript, objects are also associative arrays (or hashes). That is, the property

```
theStatus.Home
```

can also be read or written by calling

```
theStatus['Home']
```

[Objects as associative arrays](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html)

[Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: What about compatibility?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in this case, but I believe it's non-standard and browser-dependent: in Chrome, bracket notation allows you to reference style properties using their actual CSS name, instead of the camelCased version. In Firefox, it doesn't work. I haven't tested other browsers.

You can try it with Chrome on this very page, from the console:

```
document.body.style['background-color'] = 'red'
```

Comment: No it's the same, like z-index the name for manipulate element with javascript is a little different :)

Comment: I know, what I'm saying is that Chrome allows, `el.style.zIndex`, `el.style['zIndex']` and (which is unusual) `el.style['z-index']`.

Comment: I understand, just have to use the right names and there are no problems ;)